# 'undefined index' when trying to parse JSON string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I think there is some syntaxing error or conceptual error.

I have a simple AJAX call where I'm passing a JSON string to a PHP file. 
This is what the AJAX call looks like:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#btn").click(function() { 

      var id = $('#id').val(); 
      var name = $('#name').val(); 
      var Address = $('#Address').val(); 

      $.ajax({ 
        url: "connection.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        data: { topost : "{id':'" + id + "','name':'" + name + "','Address':'" + Address + "'}"}, 
        datatype: "jsonp", 
        success: function (status) { 
          if (status.success == false) { 
            alert("Failure!"); 
          } else { 
            alert("Success!"); 
          } 
        }}); 
     }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

This is how I'm trying to parse the string in my server side PHP file:

```
<?php 
  header('Content-type: application/json'); 
  $server = "localhost"; 
  $username = "root"; 
  $password = ""; 
  $database = "jqueryex"; 
  $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password); 
  if($con) { echo "Connected to database!"; } 
  else { echo "Could not connect!"; } 
  //or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); 

  mysql_select_db($database, $con); 
  $thedata= json_decode($_POST['topost']); 
  echo ($thedata); 
  mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

#### My question is:

Why do I get an error of `'undefined index topost'` at the line where it says:

```
$thedata= json_decode($_POST['topost']);
```

My `topost` comes from my AJAX, right? So why is it 'undefined' in my PHP?

Comment: Is the error more specific than just "undefined symbol?"

Comment: The error is `undefined symbol`.  If the problem was with the existence of `$_POST['topost']`, the error would have read - undefined index "topost"

Comment: Yes im sorry, thats what the error is. I have edited my question now

Comment: I saw in my google chrome console, on clicking the submit button i get an error: OPTIONS file:///C:/workspace/Settling/assets/www/connection.php Resource failed to load Why is this so? The php file located on my localhost. How to tell ajax that is where my connection.php is?

Comment: You need to give the path of your `connection.php` file.  If your file is located within a folder and not in your web root, then you can give it a path like this - `/FOLDER_NAME/connection.php`.  Note the first `/` - this says that the path is relative to your web root.

Comment: Thank you. Now im getting this error:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/connection.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Sorry - your questions now are different from your original post.  If you have a new question - post a new one.  Don't forget to search for similar questions/answers before posting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just flying by here and this might not be your problem at all, but PHP does not parse json in the body automatically when you consume Content-Type: application/json. The variables specified like that does not show up in the $_POST variable.

You have to parse the body yourself, which is not as difficult as it sounds.. something simple like this will import the json body into the _POST variable. This is not the safest implementation, and I don't recommend using it like this without sanitization:

```
$_POST=array_merge($_POST,json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are structuring your `data` object incorrectly, it should be:

```
data: {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    ... ect
}
```

You are passing `topost` as a string, while it should be an Object

Comment: He is sending a single post parameter as a JSON string (he *could* do it your way as well and it would probably be simpler) but that doesn't mean what he's doing is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Your quotes don't match (you don't have an opening quote for the `id` key of the object)
2. JSON requires double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` for quoting identifiers.

Try this:

```
data: {
  topost: '{"id":"'+id+'","name":"'+name+'","Address":"'+Address+'"}'
},
```

Alternatively you can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to encode an object literal:

```
data: {
  topost: JSON.stringify({id: id, name: name, Address: Address})
},
```

You can use Douglas Crockfords [JSON2.js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) to provide this functionality to browsers that don't support it natively.

Comment: I saw in my google chrome console, on clicking the submit button i get an error:
OPTIONS file:///C:/workspace/Settling/assets/www/connection.php Resource failed to load
Why is this so?
The php file located on my localhost.  How to tell ajax that is where my connection.php is?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what is causing your problems, but you can improve the way you construct your data object for sending -

```
var id = $('#id').val(); 
var name = $('#name').val(); 
var Address = $('#Address').val();

var dataObj = {};
dataObj.id=id;
dataObj.name=name;
dataObj.Address=Address;

$.ajax({ 
  url: "connection.php", 
  type: "POST", 
  data: { 'topost' : dataObj },
  datatype: "jsonp", 
  ...
```

Comment: I saw in my google chrome console, on clicking the submit button i get an error: OPTIONS file:///C:/workspace/Settling/assets/www/connection.php Resource failed to load Why is this so? The php file located on my localhost. How to tell ajax that is where my connection.php is?